# How to open any specific scene when the game opens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is that, how can I set any scene in unity as first scene (means it will open first when the game starts).

As I started making my game in unity, instead of making main menu I made LEVEL 1, and as a result when the game opens it directly starts the game by showing level 1.

So how can I set my main menu as the first scene

Comment: You change the default scene in the build settings. https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/BuildSettings.html

Answer (score 6):

To further upon Retired Ninja's comment, to set a specific default scene when the game opens, you need to set the ordering of the scenes so that the one you want to start with is first, see the picture below:

[image]

The main menu screen comes first in the list of scenes, this means it will run on startup.

More details here where it has been answered on the Unity Forums:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/44953/set-first-scene.html